# Can I run a jenkins plugin without using Jenkins UI?

Tags: java, jenkins

I inherited a one-class Jenkins plugin. It imports a bunch of stuff from the Jenkins `hudson` namespace. I see `pom.xml` has

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.583</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

The plugin reads a file and hits an API. I'd love to be able to just run the class outside of jenkins, so I can modify and test the API calls locally, without having to create a new `hpi` and upload to Jenkins each time - or even have to exit my terminal.

I have a `test.java` file where I want to instantiate the class and run some methods.

From my terminal I am running this:
`javac -cp '.:target/what-maven-exported.jar' foo.java && java Foo`

I get an error that it can't access `Recorder` because `class file for hudson.tasks.Recorder not found`.

Is my ask flat out impossible? Or can I fake the parent POM locally? I tried to do that, but got lost fast, and it would say the jar is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled down the hudson core JAR file and had that in my classpath, which resolved the compile time issue.

I then pulled down a couple more JARs for the runtime, added them to classpath for `java`, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [Plugin Tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-DebuggingaPlugin), you can use the `hpi:run` maven goal to launch a Jenkins instance with your plugin pre-installed:

```
mvn hpi:run
```

This was very helpful to me when hacking on a plugin. I assume this is what you actually mean with "running locally" ;-)

Comment: Sorry for delay in getting back to your quick response - got caught up in other things at work!

This isn't what I was looking for since it still entails rebuilding hpi each time I want to test a change, rather than just calling the class directly which is a faster process. I am already running jenkins locally, but want to do actions from my plugin task without going into UI.